# How to set Format Textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to format the textbox. 
For example: 
the textbox value should be in format "1 1/2"
or in date format "99-99-9999" (dd-mm-Y)
if the format is not followed it will return false.
I need to do this in jquery or in javascript

Comment: Google `input masking`

Comment: check http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/

Answer (score 0):

If i understood corectly your Q, date format you can check by using JS split().

```
var myDateString = "99-99-9999";
var mySplitResult = myDateString.split("-");
```

It will create array.You will get elements like

```
mySplitResult[0].length;
```

//output - 2

```
mySplitResult[1].length;
```

//output - 2

```
mySplitResult[2].length;
```

//output - 4

And after you can do your check.

Like:

```
if (mySplitResult[0].length == 2 || mySplitResult[1].length == 2 || mySplitResult[2].length == 4)
{
  //true
}else
{
 $(".panel").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';
    $('#date').mask('99-99-9999');
});
```